# Custom Dataflow App Stuck in Deploying State

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I created a custom s3-sink app for Spring Cloud Dataflow but during stream deployment the app maintains the `Deploying` status. I included the both the web and acutuator dependencies but I am still facing the same issue. I believe the app itself is working as it adds data to the s3-bucket but after some time the app will show `Failed` status and I get the following warnings.

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m54s (x4 over 7m54s)  kubelet, ip-x-x-x-x.ec2.internal  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m45s (x15 over 8m4s)  kubelet, ip-x-x-x-x.ec2.internal  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

I am deploying this app as a dockerized image of a maven project in a Kubernetes environmnet. Here is my code for the custom app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties.class)
public class SpringCloudCustomApp {
    
        @Autowired
        private Properties AWSProperties;
        
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT)
        public void handleMessage(String msg) throws InterruptedException {

                
                Regions clientRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;
                
                //TODO: add batch size to config

                //Generate Unique ID
                String uuid = (UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                //Add Unique ID prefix to file name
                String outName = uuid + "-" + AWSProperties.getFileObjKeyName();

                try {

                    //Generate AWS Credentials using Properties class
                    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWSProperties.getAccessKey(), AWSProperties.getSecretKey());
                    //Create S3 Client
                    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(clientRegion).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();
        
                    // Upload a text string as a new object.
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentType("application/json");
                    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes());
                    s3Client.putObject(AWSProperties.getBucketName(), outName, targetStream, metadata);

                
                } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                    // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
                    // it, so it returned an error response.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SdkClientException e) {
                    // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
                    // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudCustomApp.class, args);
        }
            
}
```

EDIT: When I deploy the maven project locally the app is able to fully deploy with no issues so my issue seems to be related to either the docker image or the deployment on a kubernetes environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what are your `readiness` and `liveness` probe endpoints. By default, SCDF sets the Spring Boot actuator endpoints as the probe endpoints.

Depending on what version of Spring Boot you use, you would end up with the following probe endpoints:

For Spring Boot 1.x:

```
Readiness: /info
Liveness: /health
```

For Spring Boot 2.x:

```
Readiness: /actuator/info
Liveness: /actuator/health
```

This means you need to enable these management endpoints in your app. For instance, I need to have properties like these:

I believe both the `health` and `info` endpoints are enabled by default in Spring Boot 1.x (you can enable them in case if it isn't the case).

But, in Spring Boot 2.x, you need to enable them explicitly. So, you need something like this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
```

Comment: I tried including health and info with your method as well as disabling those probe endpoints but the issue remains. I feel it has something to do with the docker image not being properly recognized as live by kubernetes pods which causes the pods to restart and eventually terminate. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I was able to find a workaround where I deploy two different streams on spring cloud at the same time, the one I am trying to deploy time | httpclient | custom-sink and another using time | httpclient | jdbc. When I do this, my custom sink app is able to deploy but the time and httpclient apps won't fully deploy until I un-deploy the second the stream using those apps. From this I am assuming that if the custom-sink app deploys first then there is no issue but that doens't help me resolve why this problem is happening in the first place. Hoping this provides some insight into the problem.